# Save before custom fields load overwrites with blank record

Tags: activity

Is there a patch for this.

I have an activity with quite a lot of custom fields and lookup fields.   The loading of the custom section takes quite a time, but the Save button is already displayed.

If you hit the SAVE before the custom fields are loaded, then the record is saved with blank data - overwriting the existing data.

It does not validate against the custom data - otherwise that would fail - it goes direct to overwriting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any kind of patch that would help you. The easiest way to achieve what you want would be through a simple java script which disables/hides the save button until the page is fully loaded.

For this you would need to create an extension.